# Pulling featured image as a background on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, background, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to figure out how to pull the featured post image as a background (on Wordpress) but cannot get it to work.
See below the code I'm using. $thumbimg should be pulling the featured image but obviously i am doing something wrong there.

```
            $lessons = get_posts( $args );

                        if( count( $lessons ) > 0 ) {

                            $html .= '<section class="module-lessons">';

                                $html .= '<header><h3>' . __( 'Lessons', 'sensei_modules' ) . '</h3></header>';
                                 $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($lesson->ID), array( 200,200 ), false, '' );

                                $html .= '<ul>';

                                    foreach( $lessons as $lesson ) {
                                        $html .= '<li class="lesson-items" style="background: url(<?php echo $thumbimg[0]; ?>)>';
                                        $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( intval( $lesson->ID ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( intval( $lesson->ID ) ) ) . '">' . get_the_title( intval( $lesson->ID ) ) . '</a>';

                                        $html .= '</li>';                                           

                                        // Build array of displayed lesson for exclusion later
                                        $displayed_lessons[] = $lesson->ID;
                                    }

                                $html .= '</ul>';

                            $html .= '</section>';

                        }
```

I cannot also seem to get the style="background.." to read the php as I would like to.

Comment: What's actually being rendered when you load this page?

Comment: It's showing featured posts (lessons) but the featured image code ($thumbimg) is something i added

Comment: I mean what is actually generated by the PHP when you load the page, show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work because you are getting the ID wrong. The code for the thumbnail should be something like:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_ID), 'large' ) ;
```

you are doing it right except for the fact that you are calling the `$lesson->ID` on an object `$lesson` that doesn't exist outside of the loop after it :)

Editing your code:

```
        $lessons = get_posts( $args );

                    if( count( $lessons ) > 0 ) {

                        $html .= '<section class="module-lessons">';

                            $html .= '<header><h3>' . __( 'Lessons', 'sensei_modules' ) . '</h3></header>';

                            $html .= '<ul>';

                                foreach( $lessons as $lesson ) {
                                    // This should be inside the loop
                                    $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($lesson->ID), array( 200,200 ), false, '' );
                                    $html .= '<li class="lesson-items" style="background-image: url("'. $thumbimg[0] . '")>';
                                    $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( intval( $lesson->ID ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( intval( $lesson->ID ) ) ) . '">' . get_the_title( intval( $lesson->ID ) ) . '</a>';

                                    $html .= '</li>';                                           

                                    // Build array of displayed lesson for exclusion later
                                    $displayed_lessons[] = $lesson->ID;
                                }

                            $html .= '</ul>';

                        $html .= '</section>';

                    }
```

As for the background in CSS, use `background-image:  url ()`

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Just some problem I had before as well. 
See a screenshot here: http://postimg.org/image/sa0bre7kj/ 
For some reason the PHP closing tag is not working as expected

Comment: you are missing one single quote after the closing tag :) check the code i posted above and please accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: I still get parse error for that line. Have a look here (the full code) http://pastebin.com/i8442QKj - line 543

Comment: replace line 543 with   `$html .= '<li class="lesson-items" style="background-image: url("' . echo $thumbimg[0]; . '")>';`

Comment: so you have any luck ?

Comment: Hmm, I tested this but I still get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)" on line 543

Comment: oops my bad .. there shouldnt be an echo there :) just remove it

Comment: Thanks for helping! but now i get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in... "

Comment: these errors are easy to debug .. i cannot keep track of what can go with your code especially when i dont have useful debug information like line numbers :)